# HTML radio button submit to server side

Tags: php, html

I've ran into a problem that would need some guidance.

I have this as my html:

```
Avatar: <br />
<input type="radio" id="avatar" name="avatar" value="Option1"/><img src="" alt="">
<input type="radio" id="avatar" name="avatar" value="Option2"/><img src="" alt="">
```

I'm familiar with PHP, I just need a quick push. I basically don't want a user inputting their own URL for an avatar they want for the comment when posting. So what I'm asking is, how would I set this up for PHP so if they chose "**Option 1**" the value would be **images/option1.png**

and it'd be inserted into the database. I have most of the stuff set up, I'm just confused how to work it with radio buttons.

So an easier way to understand this would be:

$Option1=images/option1.png 
$Option2=images/option2.png

If you get what I mean. Thanks!

Comment: the value selected will be in the $_POST or $_GET array

Answer (score 1):

Change your radio buttons to have image path as the value.

```
Avatar: <br />
<input type="radio" id="avatar1" name="avatar" value="images/option1.png"/>
<input type="radio" id="avatar2" name="avatar" value="images/option2.png"/>
```

This is the simplest way. But this has so many issues validating and cannot recommend.

I would recommend

```
Avatar: <br />
<input type="radio" id="avatar1" name="avatar" value="Option1"/>
<input type="radio" id="avatar2" name="avatar" value="Option1"/>
```

Then i your server side code

```
if(isset($_POST['avatar'])){
    if($_POST['avatar'] == "Option1"){
       $selected_avatar = "images/option1.png";
    }
    else{
        $selected_avatar = "images/option2.png";
    }
}
```

As a **beginner** this will work for you.

Comment: easier to use an array with multiple options `$opt=array('Option1'=>'images/option1.png','Option2'=>'images/option2.png');`